# Table is not formed out of multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is the jsfiddle I'm referring to:
http://jsfiddle.net/utdAm/212/

I just need to show the same table in my web page. But it just shows the headings in html not the content which is processed in JavaScript.

My complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>M</th>
        <th>T</th>
        <th>W</th>
        <th>T</th>
        <th>F</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: prayerData">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: index"></td>  <!-- Display the current row -->
            <td data-bind="text: M"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: T"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: W"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: T"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: F"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
var dataFromServer = {
    "Morn.": {
        "M": "M,1",
        "T": "T,1",
        "W": "W,1",
        "T": "T,1",
        "F": "F,1"
    },
    "Noon": {
        "M": "M,2",
        "T": "T,2",
        "W": "W,2",
        "T": "T,2",
        "F": "F,2"
    },
    "Even.": {
         "M": "M,3",
        "T": "T,3",
        "W": "W,3",
        "T": "T,3",
        "F": "F,3"
    },

};



var ViewModel = function(data) {

    //map data to an array
    var mappedToArray = [];
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        mappedToArray.push(item);
        item.index = index;
    });

    this.prayerData = ko.observableArray(mappedToArray);          
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(dataFromServer));
</script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Result is:

[image]

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.0.0.js include this file

Comment: I hope i have answered your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using code in jsfiddle you can also look for external sources towards your left.

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.0.0.js"></script>
```